# Registration with the server failed while configuring Amabri on CentoS 7

Tags: linux, centos

I am working on CentOs 7 and I have built ambari server from source by cahanging all python 2.6 yo 2.7
I could built them sucessfully except shell. 
When I am trying to configure server at step 3. while registering the server it fails. There is no visible error. 
Please help
PFB the log on UI

`Registration log for al1.iitkgp.ernet.in

==========================

## Copying common functions script...

Command start time 2014-10-13 13:03:24

scp /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ambari_commons
host=al1.iitkgp.ernet.in, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-10-13 13:03:24

==========================

## Copying OS type check script...

Command start time 2014-10-13 13:03:24

scp /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ambari_server/os_check_type.py
host=al1.iitkgp.ernet.in, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-10-13 13:03:25

==========================

## Running OS type check...

Command start time 2014-10-13 13:03:25
Cluster primary/cluster OS type is redhat7 and local/current OS type is redhat7

Connection to al1.iitkgp.ernet.in closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=al1.iitkgp.ernet.in, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-10-13 13:03:26

==========================

## Checking 'sudo' package on remote host...

Command start time 2014-10-13 13:03:26
sudo-1.8.6p7-11.el7.x86_64

Connection to al1.iitkgp.ernet.in closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=al1.iitkgp.ernet.in, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-10-13 13:03:28

==========================

## Copying repo file to 'tmp' folder...

Command start time 2014-10-13 13:03:28

scp /etc/yum.repos.d/ambari.repo
host=al1.iitkgp.ernet.in, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-10-13 13:03:28

==========================

## Moving file to repo dir...

Command start time 2014-10-13 13:03:28

Connection to al1.iitkgp.ernet.in closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=al1.iitkgp.ernet.in, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-10-13 13:03:29

==========================

## Copying setup script file...

Command start time 2014-10-13 13:03:29

scp /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ambari_server/setupAgent.py
host=al1.iitkgp.ernet.in, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-10-13 13:03:30

==========================

## Running setup agent script...

Command start time 2014-10-13 13:03:30
Verifying Python version compatibility...
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.7
ambari-agent is not running. No PID found at /var/run/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.pid
Restarting ambari-agent
Verifying Python version compatibility...
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.7
ambari-agent is not running. No PID found at /var/run/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.pid
Verifying Python version compatibility...
Using python  /usr/bin/python2.7
Checking for previously running Ambari Agent...
Starting ambari-agent
Verifying ambari-agent process status...
Ambari Agent successfully started
Agent PID at: /var/run/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.pid
Agent out at: /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.out
Agent log at: /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.log
('        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xe7100000-e7200000

lo: flags=73  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 3809  bytes 1003368 (979.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 3809  bytes 1003368 (979.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099  mtu 1500
        ether f2:1d:75:6c:3c:39  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

', None)

Connection to al1.iitkgp.ernet.in closed.
SSH command execution finished
host=al1.iitkgp.ernet.in, exitcode=0
Command end time 2014-10-13 13:03:35

Registering with the server...
Registration with the server failed.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my bad. I depended on UI log of Ambari. But the actual log can be found at `var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-agent.log`. I have looked in to the log file and found that CentOS 7 is nonsupported OS. hence I installed CentOs6.5 and installed HDP2.1. successfully (therewhere some glitches, but rectified some how).

Thanks
Sree